# My code to get number of records in JSON object not working?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am sending a query to a spreadsheet in google drive using the query feature of Google visualization API. I am doing the following to parse the server response:

```html
   var m= JSON.stringify(response);

   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(m);
```

This is the output when I print variable m to the screen:

```html
"U2" : "799487391",
  "Wv" : [  ],
  "Xv" : [  ],
  "hra" : "0.6",
  "p3" : "ok",
  "q" : "{\"cols\":[{\"id\":\"A\",\"label\":\"PSUID\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"B\",\"label\":\"FirstName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"C\",\"label\":\"LastName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"D\",\"label\":\"Age\",\"type\":\"number\",\"pattern\":\"General\"},{\"id\":\"E\",\"label\":\"Street\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"F\",\"label\":\"City\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"G\",\"label\":\"State\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"H\",\"label\":\"Zipcode\",\"type\":\"number\",\"pattern\":\"General\"},{\"id\":\"I\",\"label\":\"PhoneNumber\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"J\",\"label\":\"PSUEmail\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"K\",\"label\":\"ApplySemYear\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"L\",\"label\":\"Major\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"M\",\"label\":\"ColegeFrom\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"N\",\"label\":\"VolType\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"O\",\"label\":\"WhyVol\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"P\",\"label\":\"MajorHours\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"Q\",\"label\":\"ClassName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"R\",\"label\":\"ClassHours\",\"type\":\"number\",\"pattern\":\"General\"},{\"id\":\"S\",\"label\":\"OrgName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"T\",\"label\":\"OrgHours\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"U\",\"label\":\"Skills\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"V\",\"label\":\"ExtraActivities\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"W\",\"label\":\"AdditionalInfo\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"X\",\"label\":\"Agreement\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"Y\",\"label\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"Z\",\"label\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"rows\":[{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"123456789\"},{\"v\":\"Jack\"},{\"v\":\"Sanders\"},{\"v\":33,\"f\":\"33\"},{\"v\":\"345 Evergreen Drive\"},{\"v\":\"New York City\"},{\"v\":\"NY\"},{\"v\":34322,\"f\":\"34322\"},{\"v\":\"233-232-3433\"},{\"v\":\"jack@psu.edu\"},{\"v\":\"spring 2015\"},{\"v\":\"EE\"},{\"v\":\"PSU\"},{\"v\":\"Intern\"},{\"v\":\"Class credit\"},{\"v\":\"none\"},{\"v\":\"EE 2322\"},{\"v\":34,\"f\":\"34\"},{\"v\":\"none\"},{\"v\":\"none\"},{\"v\":\"nothing\"},{\"v\":\"nothing\"},{\"v\":\"nothing\"},{\"v\":\"terms agreed\"},null,{\"v\":null}]}]}"
```

I'm not sure if this is a valid JSON structure but that is how I get the response from the google visualization API query to the sreadsheet. This is the output when I print `obj.q`

```html
{ "cols" : [ { "id" : "A",
        "label" : "PSUID",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "B",
        "label" : "FirstName",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "C",
        "label" : "LastName",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "D",
        "label" : "Age",
        "pattern" : "General",
        "type" : "number"
      },
      { "id" : "E",
        "label" : "Street",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "F",
        "label" : "City",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "G",
        "label" : "State",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "H",
        "label" : "Zipcode",
        "pattern" : "General",
        "type" : "number"
      },
      { "id" : "I",
        "label" : "PhoneNumber",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "J",
        "label" : "PSUEmail",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "K",
        "label" : "ApplySemYear",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "L",
        "label" : "Major",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "M",
        "label" : "ColegeFrom",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "N",
        "label" : "VolType",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "O",
        "label" : "WhyVol",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "P",
        "label" : "MajorHours",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "Q",
        "label" : "ClassName",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "R",
        "label" : "ClassHours",
        "pattern" : "General",
        "type" : "number"
      },
      { "id" : "S",
        "label" : "OrgName",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "T",
        "label" : "OrgHours",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "U",
        "label" : "Skills",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "V",
        "label" : "ExtraActivities",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "W",
        "label" : "AdditionalInfo",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "X",
        "label" : "Agreement",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "Y",
        "label" : "",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      { "id" : "Z",
        "label" : "",
        "type" : "string"
      }
    ],
  "rows" : [ { "c" : [ { "v" : "123456789" },
            { "v" : "Jack" },
            { "v" : "Sanders" },
            { "f" : "33",
              "v" : 33
            },
            { "v" : "345 Evergreen Drive" },
            { "v" : "New York City" },
            { "v" : "NY" },
            { "f" : "34322",
              "v" : 34322
            },
            { "v" : "233-232-3433" },
            { "v" : "jack@psu.edu" },
            { "v" : "spring 2015" },
            { "v" : "EE" },
            { "v" : "PSU" },
            { "v" : "Intern" },
            { "v" : "Class credit" },
            { "v" : "none" },
            { "v" : "EE 2322" },
            { "f" : "34",
              "v" : 34
            },
            { "v" : "none" },
            { "v" : "none" },
            { "v" : "nothing" },
            { "v" : "nothing" },
            { "v" : "nothing" },
            { "v" : "terms agreed" },
            null,
            { "v" : null }
          ] } ]
}
```

I am trying to get the number of records in the "rows" property which you see in the json code just immediately above this sentence.  I have tried this `obj.q.rows.length` but that fails and returns `undefined`.

I have tried this also, but it does not work:

```html
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {

   if (key="rows"){ 
      var numberofRecords = value.length;
      alert(numberofRecords); 
      } 
   
  });
```

This is the output: `1698` which is not what I'm looking for.  It is returning the length of the string represented by the property named q. I need the number of records in the "rows" property.  How can I do this? I am new to JSON, javascript and programming in general. Your help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following code but it fails at the line `var requiredRowLength = jsonObj.rows[0].c.length;`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
      packages: ["table"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    function initialize() {
      // The URL of the spreadsheet to source data from.
      var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lABvoEQoUw8WEu9P6C2-RUesN--PB7DVV90Deq5nYfQ/gviz/tq?sheet=app&tq=select+B+where+A="111111"');

      query.send(processResponse);
    }

    function processResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {


        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      } else {


        var m = JSON.stringify(response);

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(m);

        var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(obj.q);
        alert('testing before');
        var requiredRowLength = jsonObj.rows[0].c.length;
        alert('testing after');

      }


    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="json">



  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The alert box with the message "testing before" shows on the screen but no the alert box with the message "testing after". This means that the javascript engine is failing at this line: `var requiredRowLength = jsonObj.rows[0].c.length;`.  This only happens when I search the spreadsheet with a query whoes parameter does not match a cell value in the sheet, otherwise this code does work.

For instance, the value `111111` in `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lABvoEQoUw8WEu9P6C2-RUesN--PB7DVV90Deq5nYfQ/gviz/tq?sheet=app&tq=select+B+where+A="111111"` does not exist in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(obj.q);
var requiredRowLength = jsonObj.rows[0].c.length;
```

Comment: or var jsonObj = JSON.parse(obj.q); for anyone who reads this and isn't using jQuery

Comment: @ObiOnuorah agreed :) The OP has posted using JQuery and hence I used the same. Or, they can just do - `var jsonObj = eval('('+obj.q+')');`

Comment: Arin, I have tried your code and it works but I if search the spreadsheet with a query for a value that does not exist in the spreadsheet I do not see  an alert box stating the number of elements.  So, I am assuming that the java engine in the browser crashes at this line `var requiredRowLength = jsonObj.rows[0].c.length;` Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Post your JS code where you have implemented the search and where it is failing

Comment: @ArinCool I have posted the JS code above in my original question labeled "UPDATE".  So if there are no records the rows property will be like this "rows:[ ]". Thanks.

Comment: @ArinCool Actually, I just figured it out. Use should use this instead `var requiredRowLength = jsonObj.rows.length;`. That works without any issues.

Comment: Yes, depends on what you need to loop on.